# Strange object member behaviour with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Currently I'm trying to set the properties of an object using the square bracket notation. Code is as follows

```
var obj = {};
obj['c9c4d17a698ace65c80416112da3ff66e652ec013222f5b458a1dd4950580e77'] = 'one';
obj['8d207abeb95e36abfa2cdae6ac700e776c982ec64bcbfd501cb48fec55a13a77'] = 'two';
```

If you then do a `console.log(obj)` or `console.dir(obj)` the result is

```
{ c9c4d17a698ace65c80416112da3ff66e652ec013222f5b458a1dd4950580e77: 'one',
'8d207abeb95e36abfa2cdae6ac700e776c982ec64bcbfd501cb48fec55a13a77': 'two' }
```

What I want to know is why one property key is set as an unquoted literal and the other is set as a string. They are both being set in the same way. Am I falling victim to some escape sequence within the key?

`node --version` is `v0.10.33` on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time your object key starts with a number, it will appear as quoted when inspected in the console.

This doesn't affect any internal representation.  These keys are always strings, as-assigned.  It's just that when you inspect them, they'll only be quoted if they need to be (such as when they contain a reserved character or start with a number).

Comment: So interfacing with the object is the same for both, except you can't use dot notation on the one that begins with a number I presume?